# Alphabetic sorting fails in biblatex when defining characters with \newcommand

Tags: biblatex, fontspec, sorting

I'm citing an Icelandic guy whose last name has a first character Á (U+00C1). If I write his name in my bibliography with that character code (`\char"00C1`), the sorting works correctly. If, however, I define the character Á as `\auppercaseacute` in my preamble with `\newcommand`, the sorting fails. What is going on here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
%\newcommand{\auppercaseacute}{\char"00C1}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{mccartney1974,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "A cool book about guitars",
    YEAR = "1974"}
@BOOK{arnason2007,
    TITLE = "Íslensk orðabók",
    YEAR = "2007",
    EDITOR = "Mörður {\char"00C1}rnason"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{mccartney1974}{arnason2007}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\newcommand{\auppercaseacute}{\char"00C1}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{mccartney1974,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "A cool book about guitars",
    YEAR = "1974"}
@BOOK{arnason2007,
    TITLE = "Íslensk orðabók",
    YEAR = "2007",
    EDITOR = "Mörður {\auppercaseacute}rnason"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{mccartney1974}{arnason2007}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you can't use `Á` in this instance? I seem to remember to have read something about special treatment of `{\char"xxxx}` constructs by `biblatex`, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Biber doesn't perform macro expansion. The entry is alphabetized under "R".

Comment: moewe: But as you can see, {\char"xxxx} works fine. As I said in another ``biblatex`` question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65490/biblatex-apa-and-unicode-characters): I prefer defining my characters in terms of their Unicode codes, cuz then anyone can open my ``.tex`` and ``.bib`` files on any computer with any fonts, and know exactly what characters I intend to be displayed. That's a big deal in my field. Plus I use a lot of characters you can't just type on the keyboard.

Comment: @egreg: "Doesn't perform macro expansion"? It prints Á, though .. ?

Comment: I see. This [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65576/35864) (to [the question you linked to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65490/biblatex-apa-and-unicode-characters)) though states clearly what I suspected: `biblatex` converts `\char"xxxx` internally (for sorting etc.), but, as egreg says, the standard macro `\auppercaseacute` is not expanded.

Comment: @Sverre Biber prints nothing, it just *writes* a file where `\auppercaseacute` appears and is then expanded by TeX at a later stage. It can interpret `\char"abcd` sequences for sorting, but it's another matter.

Comment: So bottom line is 'don't use macros in your ``.bib`` file' (at least not in words that are subject to sorting).

Comment: @Sverre If you are concerned with sorting, just say `\newcommand{\auppercaseacute}[1]{\char"00C1}` and use `{\auppercaseacute{A}}rnason` in the `.bib` file. But I'd not worry too much: if somebody is UTF-8 impaired it's their fault.

Comment: @egreg I prefer to avoid situations where those who are "UTF-8 impaired" can't see the characters I intend. It's also a question of software (I often experience brand new versions of web browsers not being able to display anything outside of ASCII) or fonts (not all common fonts have the characters I use in my ``.bib`` files).

Comment: The problem is, though, that ``biber`` doesn't appear to convert many of the ``\char"xxxx`` commands either, cf. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/167

Comment: This should be fixed in biber 1.8. The problem was when wrapped in braces it would try to remove braces first which is fraught with problems. Now it doesn't try to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in biber 1.8. The problem was when wrapped in braces it would try to remove braces first which is fraught with problems. Now it doesn't try to do this.